# Fix Excel time in two different formats 1:10=1min10sec & 27:55:00=27min55sec0ms

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I've got 2k rows of time (from a Toshiba fax log) in two different formats

- 1:10     = 1min 10sec
- 27:55:00 = 27min 55sec 0ms

I want to total/sum this time column however it calculates wrong (5:05 instead of the actual 29:05) maybe because it thinks the second time format is hours? I can't seem to format or convert these in a second column with a formula so I can get a grand total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If excel is seeing them as times then simply divide by 60:

```
=A1/60
```

then sum the results.

[image]

Comment: Gosh what an easy fix, a follow-up question if you can: how to convert the subtotal so its just minutes in number (decimal or integer) format? So in your example it'd be 29 rounded

Comment: Scratch that I got it: `=HOUR(B3)*60+MINUTE(B3)+SECOND(B3)/60`

Comment: @gregg , Without a helper column it could be `=SUM(A1:A2)/60`. For a number it would be: `=(SUM(A1:A2)/60)*1440`